# Function to turn text into voice while using skype or similar on iPhone

Tags: iphone, skype

so ideally I would like to type and turn the text into voice that speaks to the person on the other end of skype, on my iphone, is there something like that? Doesn't have to be skype if there is another app that can phone and do this type-to-voice function simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

A cursory search of the App Store reveals [iSpeech](https://appsto.re/us/RULnt.i), which is basic and doesn't have the greatest reviews, but looks like it will suffice. There are many more applications available simply search "text to speech" on the App Store.